# Is it really harmful to my iPhone if I often debug with it?

Tags: ios, iphone

Most of my frends said yes,but my master said no.So I wonder whether it's really bad to my iPhone if I always debug with it and why.

Comment: No. Absolutely not 

Comment: This question isn't coding related. My option is no, not at all.

Comment: Only if you really get frustrated, and throw it to the ground when stuff doesn't work. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to judge。。。 In my experience for a long time on the phone debugging power consumption of the program, attached to the data line, the phone battery will have some damage.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's fine to use. Especially when you shut it down after coding as it will clear the RAM memory just to be sure (incase of memory leaks).

Answer (score 0):

I have iPhone 4 and iPhone 5s, I used both to develop iOS app for 4 years. And it seems debug on iPhone make it battery live longer because it always use power from your mac.
Only using iPhone with high power require will make its battery go down, especially heavy games or turn on 3G/4G all the time.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it doesn't impact battery/performance much unless you keep it connected for a long time every day. It has one advantage as well when you connect a device to mac it charges with mac high voltage, which is good for the long term.

The battery/performance will be drained from these factors only:

1. You install an app via debugger that has memory leaks. It'll keep draining resources.
2. You install an app via debugger that is doing a lot of background activity or which uses a lot of background features like location etc.

If you follow the proper battery optimization guide, it's all good. Here's the official [link](https://www.apple.com/in/batteries/maximizing-performance/).